# Move_uploaded_file doens't work?

Tags: php, html

The problem I have is that my move_uploaded_file doesn't work.

I have the following code:

```
<input type="file" name="image<?=$a; ?>" />
```

**$a** is a variable to define each of the inputs because I have 4 ( I have them in a while)

The **form** has `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

The directory **exists**.

The following code is the php code I used to get the images

```
for($a=1; $a<=4; $a++){
    $diretor = "../images/imprensa/".$_FILES['image'.$a]['name'];
    $image = basename($_FILES['image'.$a]['tmp_name']);
if(move_uploaded_file($image, $diretor)){
      echo "yey";
    }else{
      echo "Oh";
    }
}
```

Already tried to print the variables and I get both temp_name and basename but the code doesn't seem to work

Where is the error here?
***EDIT***

The `move_uploaded_file` is **INSIDE** `for`, sorry for not clearing it out

Comment: You need to move tmp_file with all path, not only basename. `move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image'.$a]['tmp_name'], ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `basename()` on the `tmp_name` parameter. The first argument to `move_uploaded_file` must be a `tmp_name` parameter. On the other hand, you should use it on `name`, since that comes from the user, and they might try to add other directory names.

You should also call it inside the loop, otherwise you're only moving the last file.

```
for($a=1; $a<=4; $a++){
    if ($_FILES['image'.$a]['error'] == 0) {
        $diretor = "../images/imprensa/".basename($_FILES['image'.$a]['name']);
        $image = $_FILES['image'.$a]['tmp_name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($image, $diretor)){
            echo "yey";
        }else{
            echo "Oh";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! The **if** was already inside **for** but I changed basename and it worked!